# I want to add a column in my Data Frame according to some condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add another column RevisedPrice based on mentioned condition [image: see the image]

if Price=1500 then RevisedPrice=Price+(Price*0.15) else if Price=800 then RevisedPrice=Price+(Price*0.10) else RevisedPrice=Price+(Price*0.5)

Below is my code------------

```py
df['RevisedPrice']=[x+(0.15*x) if x==1500 else x+(0.10*x) if x==800 else x+(0.05*x) for x in df['Price']]
```

i am getting my column value as `RevisedPrice=Price+(Price*0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function of pandas dataframe to achieve the desired result.
Here is the code you might want to try:

```
def transform(row):
    if row["Price"] == 1500:
        scale = 0.15
    elif row["Price"] == 800:
        scale = 0.10
    else:
        scale = 0.5

    return row["Price"] + row["Price"] * scale

df["RevisedPrice"] = df.apply(transform, axis=1)
```

And when you execute `>>>print(df.head())`

**OUTPUT:**

```
         Date   Event  Price  RevisedPrice
0   11/8/2011   Music   1500        1725.0
1   11/9/2011  Poetry    800         880.0
2  11/10/2011   Music   1500        1725.0
3  11/11/2011  Comedy   1200        1800.0
4  11/12/2011  Poetry    800         880.0
```

Comment: You should avoid using ```.apply(...)```: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach with `lambda`. You can apply multiple condition with this way.

```
df['RevisedPrice'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: x*1.15 if x == 1500 else (x*1.1 if x == 800 else x*1.05))
```

Output:

```
    Event  Price  RevisedPrice
0   music   1500        1725.0
1  poetry    800         880.0
2   music   1500        1725.0
3  comedy   1200        1260.0
4  poetry    800         880.0
```

PS: I assume RevisedPrice for `else` condition is `x+(x*0.05)`. If it is `x+(x*0.5)` you can modify the condition as well.

Comment: You should avoid using ```.apply(...)```: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
mapping={1500: 1.15, 800: 1.1}
df['RevisedPrice']=df['Price'].map(mapping).fillna(1.5).mul(df['Price'])
```

So map all the `Price` to proper coefficient, fill the `else` (since `.map` maps 1:1, you can't put `else` there). Then just multiply it by the base column - `Price`